# Click on textfield instead of button Java Swings

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jframe, jtextfield

I have this code in Java Swings which creates 2 frames.The first frame contains 4 text fields(roll no,name,class,section) **leaving the text fields blank** I click on the search button in the 1st frame,another frame opens with all my table records in the database.Once I select a record(or the row) all the details of it appear in the 1st frame,i.e roll no,class,name and section get populated.
Right now I am using the search button to go to the next frame.What should I do so that the action is performed once I click on the roll no. text field instead of the search button?

This is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import java.awt.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class barcoder1 implements ActionListener{
    JFrame frame,frame1;
    JTextField textbox,textbox1,textbox2,textbox3,textbox4,textbox5,textbox6,textbox7,textbox8;
    JLabel label,label1,label2,label3,label4,label5,label6,label7,label8;
    JButton button;
    JPanel panel;
    static JTable table;

    String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb";
    String userName = "root";
    String password = "root";
    String[] columnNames = {"Roll No", "Name", "Class", "Section"};

    public void createUI()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("Database Search Result");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        textbox = new JTextField();
        textbox.setBounds(120,30,150,20); 
        label=new JLabel("Roll No.");
        label.setBounds(10, 30, 100, 20);
        textbox1 = new JTextField();
        textbox1.setBounds(120,50,150,20); 
        label1=new JLabel("Name");
        label1.setBounds(10, 50, 100, 20);
        textbox2 = new JTextField();
        textbox2.setBounds(120,70,150,20); 
        label2=new JLabel("Class");
        label2.setBounds(10, 70, 100, 20);
        textbox3 = new JTextField();
        textbox3.setBounds(120,90,150,20); 
        label3=new JLabel("Section");
        label3.setBounds(10, 90, 100, 20);
        button = new JButton("search");
        button.setBounds(120,230,150,20);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        frame.add(textbox);
        frame.add(label);
        frame.add(textbox1);
        frame.add(label1);
        frame.add(textbox2);
        frame.add(label2);
        frame.add(textbox3);
        frame.add(label3);
        frame.add(button);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(500, 400);        
    }   

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        button = (JButton)ae.getSource();
        System.out.println("Showing Table Data.......");
            showTableData();            
    }   

    public void showTableData()
    {

        frame1 = new JFrame("Database Search Result");
        //frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());       
        //TableModel tm = new TableModel();
         DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(){
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) { 
             return false;  
            }
        };
        model.setColumnIdentifiers(columnNames);
        //DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(tm.getData1(), tm.getColumnNames());      
        //table = new JTable(model);
        final JTable table = new JTable(model);
        table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                int row = table.getSelectedRow();
                System.out.println("Selecte table row = " + row);
                if (row != -1) {
                    int modelRow = table.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
                    System.out.println("Selecte model row = " + row);
                    Vector data = (Vector) ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).getDataVector().get(modelRow);
                    textbox.setText(data.get(0).toString());
                    textbox1.setText(data.get(1).toString());
                    textbox2.setText(data.get(2).toString());
                    textbox3.setText(data.get(3).toString());
                }
            }
        });
        table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e) && e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                    if (table.getSelectedRow() != -1) {
                        SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(table).dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);      
        String textvalue = textbox.getText();
        String roll= "";
        String name= "";
        String cl = "";
        String sec = "";
        try
        {           
             Class.forName(driverName);      
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
            //String sql = "select * from student where rollno = "+textvalue;
            String sql="select * from student";
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            int i =0;
            while(rs.next())
            {
                roll = rs.getString("rollno");
                name = rs.getString("name");
                cl = rs.getString("class");
                sec = rs.getString("section");                  
                model.addRow(new Object[]{roll, name, cl, sec});

            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(),"Error",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        frame1.add(scroll);
        frame1.setVisible(true);
        frame1.setSize(400,300);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        barcoder1 sr = new barcoder1();
                sr.createUI();              
    }
}
```

Comment: Add FocusListener and call the same on focusGained?

Comment: Use the same technique as you did for closing the window.  Attach a mouse listener to the field and detect the mouse clicked.  I have to say, it's an unusual method of navigation though

Comment: @MadProgrammer so should I put just showtabledata instead of SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(table).dispose();?

Comment: If `showtabledata` opens you other window, then yes.  You may, however, like to have a look at [How to make dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Comment: Nothing happens when I do this

Comment: it worked,I put the mouselistener in the showtabledata and was calling the function.my bad.Thanks once again @MadProgrammer

Comment: Nice see you it working.  And you're welcome.